# Sum the digits in a string

Tags: java

I wrote a program that sums the int values in a String. I'm getting the wrong output though. I can't quite figure out the issue. The expected output should be 23 and 29 but I am getting 263 and 269. Any suggestions would be helpful; it seems it is putting a 6 between my outputs for some reason.

```
public class ParseString
{
   String str;


   public ParseString(String x)
   {
      this.str = x;
   }


   public int sumOfAllDigits()
   {
      int total = 0;
      char[] arr = new char[this.str.length()];

      for(int i = 0; i < this.str.length(); i++)
      {
         arr[i] = this.str.charAt(i);
      }  

      for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      {

         if(arr[i] >= '0' && arr[i] <= '9')
         {
            total = total + arr[i];
         }

      } 

      return total;

   }


public class TestParseString
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String s1 = "AB458JK2L#4";
      ParseString ps1 = new ParseString(s1);
      System.out.println("Sum of all digits in \"" + s1 + "\" is: ");
      System.out.println(ps1.sumOfAllDigits());
      System.out.println();

      String s2 = "8927KL3PY";
      ParseString ps2 = new ParseString(s2);
      System.out.println("Sum of all digits in \"" + s2 + "\" is: ");
      System.out.println(ps2.sumOfAllDigits());
   }
}
```

Comment: `total = total + Integer.parseInt(arr[i] +"");` Also, instead of `if(arr[i] >= '0' && arr[i] <= '9')` you'd want `Character.isDigit(arr[i])`

Comment: What does this have to do with regex?

Comment: @Aominè why not `int value = Character.getNumericValue(arr[i]);`? Much cheaper than building a string and parsing it.

Comment: In the question you asked for sum of all ints in the string, but in the code you're looking for sum of digits?

Comment: @hotrod28 `char[] arr = this.str.toCharArray();` is a much easier way to get the chars in a string than looping like that.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yup, that's a better alternative if you care about object allocations/ performance.

Comment: Can use a foreach loop to get each char, not as big of a change as Andy's suggestions though

Comment: @phflack you shouldn't use either `toCharArray()` to loop through a string either, because it necessarily copies the string into a new char array. Either use a basic for loop and `charAt`, or the `codePoints()` stream.

Comment: Was thinking more similar to what they currently have, `char[] arr = str.toCharArray(); for(char c : arr) ...`, but yes, `charAt()` would probably be easier

Comment: `Character#getNumericValue`, since characters are themselves integer codepoints for ASCII characters

Answer (score 2):

It's not that a `6` is inserted into your sum; it's that your sum is `240` too high.  There are 5 digits in each of your test strings.  What is missing here is what goes on in the conversion between `char` and `int`.  A `'0'` is not `0`; when a `char` is widened to an `int` for summing, it takes the ASCII value, which for numbers is the represented number plus 48.  E.g. `'0'` -> `48`, `'1'` -> `49`, etc.

An extra `48` added 5 times yields an extra `240`.

Because the digits are coded in order starting with `'0'` at `48`, you can subtract `'0'` to take away the unwanted 48.

```
total = total + arr[i] - '0';
```

As an aside, as already mentioned in the comments on the question, `toCharArray()` gets you the `char[]` for a `String` more easily than manually copying each character.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
total = total + arr[i];
```

`arr[i]` is a `char`. When you use the `+` operator on it, with the other operand being an int, you are actually adding the ASCII value of the character, which is 48 to 57 for 0 to 9.

You think you are doing this:

```
4 + 5 + 8 + 2 + 4
```

But actually the program is doing:

```
52 + 53 + 56 + 50 + 52
```

So that's why you get such a large number.

You need to parse the characters to get the correct output. One way to do this is to just subtract 48!

```
total = total + (arr[i] - 48);
```

Or you can convert it to a string first, then parse it as an `int`:

```
total = total + Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(arr[i]));
```